# Will be working Sencha Touch 2.1.1 without HTML5 mobile browser support?

Tags: mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

Mobile device browser have not support html5. Will be working basic features of sencha touch 2.1.1 app on that device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha touch has support for Android, iOS, 2 BlackBerry devices (and soon WP8) Older devices / browsers are not supported and won't work propperly.

[Here](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/features/) you will find a list supported of devices.

If your device runs a webkit based browser you have a chance most of the features will work. Else I would upgrade your device or seek for another solution

Comment: Chrome, Safari or other webkit based browsers, yes. But is it working in IE? Don't think so..

Comment: http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/examples/kitchensink/index.html , my question about html5. Sencha touch using html5 features or not?

Comment: It uses css3 extensively.. (for animations an such) but core functionality would work I guess. You can't use localStorage and stuff..

Comment: Now the answer is full for me. Thank you!